# Heroku Docker - Tomcat 7 is not serving the requests

Tags: docker, heroku, tomcat7, port

Below is the Docker file:

```
FROM tomcat:7.0.90-jre7-alpine
ENV spring.profiles.active=dev 
ENV CATALINA_OPTS=" -Dlogback.ContextSelector=JNDI"

#ADD builds/lib/ILCH-*.war $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/ilch.war
ADD heroku/catalina.sh /usr/local/tomcat/bin
RUN `chmod 777 /usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh`
```

Tomcat Server is started successfully per the below logs after container released:

> heroku container:release web --app runningticker

The port assignment is good as I updated the server.xml inside the Catalina.sh before starting the server. (Last but one line in the docker file)

The requests to this application are not serving and I always see the logs code=H80 desc="Maintenance mode"

```
2018-09-22T19:38:08.446927+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Server startup in 5965 ms
2018-09-22T19:39:05.242821+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H80 desc="Maintenance mode" method=GET path="/"
host=runningticker.herokuapp.com
request_id=e1cb4819-6bd9-4b04-8fc5-09c1bb2d7ad1 fwd="72.48.50.103"
dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Expected to run the ROOT application of tomcat home page, but not.
What am I missing? Port binding while docker run? If so, how can I do this on Heroku?

If you wonder what's there in Catalina.sh this is the first line I added.

```
sed -i -e "s/8080/$PORT/" /usr/local/tomcat/conf/server.xml
```